# Is it possible to switch a payment card in wallet without user interaction?

Tags: android, nfc, android-pay, google-pay, wallet

**Is the following scenario in Android technically possible?**

1. User has an Android wallet with two payment cards, A and B. Where A is the default payment card.
2. User tries to pay contactless at a merchants terminal.
3. Payment fails for any reason.
4. The app which holds/manages the wallet (an alternative to Google Pay) detects the failed attempt and switches the payment method automatically from card A to B, without the need for the user to interact.
5. User can try again to pay contactless with card B.

Is this possible without the user confirming or triggering this change of payment card?
The whole point of this is to quickly allow a secondary card to be used as payment alternative, without manually switching for the user.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Which part exactly? switching the cards without users active manual selection?

Comment: Sorry. I misread. I thought this was for Google Pay. This is beyond my area of expertise. I would assume that if you get a notification that the payment fails that you could then do something like switching cards within your own app. However, I would also assume that the user would also have to initiate a new contactless transaction. I don't know if that counts as user interaction in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are trying to make an app like described and you are not talking about an existing app.

This is only possible if you "are a bank". (clearification below)

Because paying with NFC on your phone is like paying directly per card. The merchend charges the given card (which is presented via NFC).

If you are a bank or have the ability to implement a system like the following it would be possible.

1. Phone gets scanned at the merchand
2. You (your banking system) gets the request for charging a specific amount
3. On your backend you will try to charge the given card from the user if that failes you try to charge the users paypal or any other given payment method from the user
4. If charging the user is successful you will authorize the transaction from the merchant

I do not know if the merchant will wait long enough for your backend.

Take a look at https://www.solarisbank.com/, they offer banking service for other companies and have a "straight forward API".

Comment: Thanks for your response @Elias. Maybe my scenario was not clear. Assume an app like Google Pay. The app itself is not a bank of course, but it can hold and manage multiple payment methods. The scenario is where the first payment method got declined and the app automatically tries to pay with the secondary payment method. Without user interaction. So the user has two payment cards and when first does not work, second gets used automatically. The banks behind the cards are not relevant as they don't change anything. Just the app manages the first failed attempt with a fallback.

Comment: @Sorcerer that is exacly what I was talking about. Also there is an app like that already. Check out curve. In order to program something like that, you have to be a bank since only direct payment can be presented via NFC.  If something is still unclear feel free to ask.